# Is there an event for collapsing a rich:tree node?

Tags: java, ajax, tree, events, richfaces

I've finally managed to receive events if the user expands a node of my client side handled tree using the following method:

```
public void processExpansion(NodeExpandedEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
 if (event != null && event.getSource() != null && event.getSource() instanceof HtmlTree) {
  this.expandedNodes.add(((UITree) event.getSource()).getRowData());
 }
}
```

I had to use #getRowData() because of the recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor.

How can I get notification of nodes the user collapses again? I could not find an appropriate listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  [ChangeExpandListener](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_changeExpandListener.html)

The `<rich:changeExpandListener>` represents an action listener method that is notified on an expand/collapse event on the node.

EDIT:

First *changeExpandListener* has to be delared as attribute for `<rich:treeNode>`, if is declared for entired tree works as you write (event is processed after selection event).
So:

```
<rich:tree value="#{simpleTreeBean.treeNode}" var="item" >
    <rich:treeNode changeExpandListener="#{simpleTreeBean.processExpansion}">
         <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
    </rich:treeNode>                   
</rich:tree>
```

**processExpansion** method must take *NodeExpandedEvent* as a parameter but there is no need to implement interface *org.richfaces.event.NodeExpandedListener*.

```
public void processExpansion(NodeExpandedEvent evt) {

  Object source = evt.getSource();
  if (source instanceof HtmlTreeNode) {
    UITree tree = ((HtmlTreeNode) source).getUITree();
    if (tree == null) {
      return;
    }
    // get the row key i.e. id of the given node.
    Object rowKey = tree.getRowKey();
    // get the model node of this node.
    TreeRowKey key = (TreeRowKey) tree.getRowKey();

    TreeState state = (TreeState) tree.getComponentState();
    if (state.isExpanded(key)) {
      System.out.println(rowKey + " - expanded");
    } else {
      System.out.println(rowKey + " - collapsed");
    }
  }
}
```

That's should help

Comment: How can I distinguish collapse from expand?

I use client side collapsing and the event listener is triggered upon submit of the tree - for example when changing the selection. I get one event per expanded node at this point... could not see any for collapsed nodes so far.